# ExtJS 4.1.1: Working with a TreeGrid/TreeStore

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, treegrid

I am having some problems with my code that I hoped you could help me with as I've kind of hit a wall.

I have a field in a Tree grid that has the following properties:

```
    xtype : 'gridcolumn',
    id : 'raGridFormulaLink_Purchased',
    dataIndex: 'formulaLink',
    groupable : false,
    editor : {
        xtype: 'textfield'
    },      
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        var rVal; var linkRec;
        if(value !== '' && value !== 0) {
            /* TODO Find linked Record based on ['child_id' => value] 
             * and print that record's [text] to rVal */
            rVal = Ext.local.langstore[448] + ' ' + value;
        }
        return rVal;
    },
    align: 'left',
    width: 100
```

As  you can see I am trying to do a simple HLOOKUP to find the linked record. But I am unable to get the proper record from the store. How can I do this?

The value has the right "child_id", so it's not the input that's wrong.

Any help appreciated,

GR.

Comment: It looks to me that you need to do more research on how the Extjs model works.  This code does not make sense to me to the point that I don't even know what you're trying to do here specifically.  I think HLOOKUP is an excel function, and does not really have a simple equivalent function Extjs, even though you can do something close with a better understanding of how stores work in Extjs.

Comment: HLOOKUP is an Excel function, yes. I was simply using it to better explain what I am trying to achive. Saki (Sencha support forum) suggested to use [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-findChild) functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

Final code:

```
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        var rVal; var rText = ''; var node;

        if(value !== '' && value !== 0) {
            if(record.isLeaf()) {
                var node = record.parentNode.findChild('child_id',value);
                rText = node.data.text;
                rVal = Ext.local.langstore[448] + ' ' + rText;
            }
        }
        return rVal;
    },
```